# RegExp exec issue

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, rest

The code below verifies that the requested REST endpoint is in the form of 
'/employees/<[A-Za-z0-9_]+>" The following endpoint would be valid "/employees/100".  IF the endpoint is valid it then excludes the requested url and just passes the employee number to the emp.get procedure.  The codes is not performing the correct ReqExp.exec command and is passing /employees/100 when it should just passing 100.  I have included the log messages for empno and req.url.

I am not sure if the problem is the sql query that is getting executed or passing of the employee number to the sql query.  The sql query should be performing a where statement on employee_number column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
        var empnoPatt = "[A-Za-z0-9_]+";
        var patt = new RegExp("/employees/" + empnoPatt);
        if (patt.test(req.url)) {
            patt = new RegExp(empnoPatt);
            console.log(req.url);
            var empno = patt.exec(req.url);
            console.log(empno);
            emp.get(req, resp, empno);
        }

console.log(req.url);
/employees/100

console.log(empno);
[ 'employees', index: 1, input: '/employees/100' ]

this is the error that I am receiving when I try to search for employee 100
{ RequestError: Invalid column name 'employees'.  This is confusion to me and I am not sure why the sql query thinks employees is a column in the table.
```

This the function that gets executed that should return employee record where employee_number = 100

```
exports.get = function (req, resp, empno) {
    db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_NUMBER =" + empno, function (data, err) {
        if (err) {
            httpMsgs.show500(req, resp, err);
        }
        else {
            httpMsgs.showJSON(req, resp, data);
        }
    });
```

This is the recordset that is returned after correctly passing the employee number,

```
{
  "recordsets": [
    [
      {
        "RECORD_KEY": "951112558721130050",
        "EMPLOYEE_NUMBER": "100",
        "EMPLOYEE_FOH_LOGIN": "11",
        "EMPLOYEE_BOH_LOGIN": null,
        "EMPLOYEE_BOH_PASSWORD": "",
        "CLOCK_NUMBER": null,
        "FIRST_NAME": "SAMPLE CLERK",
        "LAST_NAME": null,
        "TRAINING_MODE": false,
        "KEY_CARD": null,
        "VERIFONE_SERVER_ID": null,
        "PAY_TYPE": 1,
        "DEFAULT_ROLE_RECORD_KEY": null,
        "CAN_EDIT_FIELD_PERMISSIONS": false,
        "PRIVILEGE_REQUIRED": null,
        "ACTIVE": true
      }
    ]
  ],
  "recordset": [
    {
      "RECORD_KEY": "951112558721130050",
      "EMPLOYEE_NUMBER": "100",
      "EMPLOYEE_FOH_LOGIN": "11",
      "EMPLOYEE_BOH_LOGIN": null,
      "EMPLOYEE_BOH_PASSWORD": "",
      "CLOCK_NUMBER": null,
      "FIRST_NAME": "SAMPLE CLERK",
      "LAST_NAME": null,
      "TRAINING_MODE": false,
      "KEY_CARD": null,
      "VERIFONE_SERVER_ID": null,
      "PAY_TYPE": 1,
      "DEFAULT_ROLE_RECORD_KEY": null,
      "CAN_EDIT_FIELD_PERMISSIONS": false,
      "PRIVILEGE_REQUIRED": null,
      "ACTIVE": true
    }
  ],
  "output": {},
  "rowsAffected": [
    1
  ]
}
```

Comment: The pattern `[A-Za-z0-9_]+` executed on `/employees/anything` will return `"employees"` as `"amployees"` is valid for `[A-Za-z0-9_]+`!

Comment: You can make use of the anchor `$` (end of the string) like this: `patt = new RegExp(empnoPatt + "$");`!

Comment: Or even better use this: `var empno = req.url.split('/')[2];` without the need of any pattern whatsoever (inside the `if` of course as the `.test` one is needed)!

Comment: ibranhim, both suggestions work but they are returning the employee record twice.  Do you know what is causing this?

Comment: @joey.coyle, you've probably added some `()` to your regex

Comment: What does _returning the employee record twice_ mean? Are you talking about the SQL query result? If so then that is beyond me as there isn't enough clues here, I would take a guess and say that you probably have duplicates in you SQL table or you're calling the `get` function twice!

Comment: you can replace your whole logic with `var empno = String(req.url.match(/\/employees\/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/) || "").split("/").pop(); if(empno) emp.get(req, resp, empno);` In this code, `empno` contains either the value you're looking for, or an empty string if there's no match.

Comment: ibrahim, I have updated the question with the recordset I am getting back.  I see that I am also getting double records when request all employees so this issue must be unrelated and I need to track down what is causing this.